# How to prevent a specific exception from being retried in RabbitMQ

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

In my Spring Boot project I'm using RabbitMQ for messaging and have two exceptions `CustomExceptionA` and `CustomExceptionB`. I want my `CustomExceptionA` to be retried n times and `CustomExceptionB` not to retry but directly sent to DLQ.

Below are my configurations:-

**yaml file**

```yaml
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    listener:
      simple:
        default-requeue-rejected: false
        retry:
          enabled: true
          initial-interval: 2s
          max-attempts: 3
          max-interval: 2s
          multiplier: 1
```

**Configuration file**

```java
 @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                               SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return new ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler(customExceptionStrategy());
    }

    @Bean
    FatalExceptionStrategy customExceptionStrategy() {
        return new CustomFatalExceptionStrategy();
    }
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@Component
public class CustomFatalExceptionStrategy extends ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.DefaultExceptionStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean isFatal(Throwable throwable) {
        return (throwable.getCause() instanceof CustomExceptionB);
    }
}
```

According to the blog : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-amqp-error-handling mechanism should work but for some reason it is not working for me.

Someone please look at the issue.

Comment: I'm currently having the same problem. Could you already find a solution?